# lenskit maven build 'failed to execute goal' error message

Tags: eclipse, maven, lenskit

I would like to be able to use LensKit - from within Eclipse (Kepler) - to explore its basic capabilities.

When building a maven project, however, I am getting the following error message:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:2.0-M2:run-eval (default-run-eval) on project lenskit-demo: Execution default-run-eval of goal org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:2.0-M2:run-eval failed: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
```

Another part of the error message directs to the following site, which is not very informative:

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Can anyone help with this? Is this something that's easily fixed?

Answer (score 1):

lenskit-demo is really out of date (I'm not even sure where it is).

Better starting points:

- http://lenskit.org/documentation/basics/getting-started/
- http://lenskit.org/documentation/evaluator/quickstart/

Comment: One remark - the hello-lenskit example in the 'getting started' section uses 'ratings.data' file as input. I haven't been able to find this file on the lens-kit website to run the example. Would it be possible to upload this file to github so that results can be replicated? Running the eval script on the movie100K dataset appears to work (although I haven't been able to exactly replicate the boxplot that's shown on the website).